# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when start NodeJS from IntellijIDEA

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, intellij-idea

I try to create hello world applications by react js. I created the NodeJS application in IntelliJ IDEA. Create a helloworld.js file. and add this code to this file

```
import React from 'react';

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Added react-dom dependency to package.json. Made npm install command. Start Application

```
{
  "name": "testjsapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  }
}
```

Error:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\projects\testjsapp\hello\helloworld.js
D:\projects\testjsapp\hello\helloworld.js:2
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You forgot about `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Comment: I add this import but still same error

Comment: you need transpiler to transform your code into es6, like babel.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to execute a React program in Node.js, but it is designed to run **in a web browser**. There is no DOM in Node.js for you to manipulate. That just isn't going to work.

Since the program you are running uses JSX, you'll need to transpile it before it will work there too.

Go back [to the tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). The [section on setting up a local development environment provides an approach to getting up and running](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment) or you can look at a [selection of toolchains](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#recommended-toolchains) that you can choose from.

Answer (score 4):

check your current version

> node -v

Update you node version to latest 13.X

[Update nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

And Execute to create React App

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

reference [To create react app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)

and cross check it your existing Application, If needed

Answer (score 1):

If you want neither using `create-react-app` nor settings up webpack and other tools, I can suggest starting with a simple HTML page that includes links to `babel-standalone` and required libraries, see https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">

    function Hello(props) {
      const [name, setName] = React.useState(props.name);
      return (
        <h1 onClick = {() => setName(Math.random().toString(36).substring(5))}>
          Hello {name}
        </h1>
      );
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Hello name='World'/>,
      document.getElementById('root'),
    );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Create an empty project, add a new HTML file, paste the content above in it, then right-click the file and choose either **Run** or **Debug** from its right-click menu to open application in browser

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked when I passed an argument to transpile imports on the fly like below -

```
// transpile imports on the fly
require("@babel/register")({
    ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
});
```

Also, I had a babel.config.js in the same folder as that of package.json for the server-side.

```
module.exports = {
presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
    "@babel/transform-arrow-functions",
    "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
],
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I imported a Module from the client `client` to the `server` folder. Although the module was not used, it seems this kind of import is forbidden,

Answer (score -1):

Well i came across same problem, i realized I wasn't doing something right.
First once you already create a react app using react-create-app
And you closed the project or run another project folder, if you want to start that project again 
Make sure the folder path is correct then simply type
        npm start in the terminal
 that will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Already the Folder Called Src inside your Reactapp --> Goto that Src Directory and Replace App.js with your code then go back to ReactApp Directory and Run the code npm start ..It works for me..

Answer (score -1):

I saw this issue when I wanted to debug my React app in IntelliJ which you do by running a `JavaScript configuration` in debug mode by e.g. `right-click app.js > debug`.

However, debugging doesn't work if your app isn't running already via `npm start` in terminal or `right-click -> run` on app.js.

So it's a two step process (in case of debugging), without step 1, syntax error message.

Answer (score -2):

replace your line

```
import React from 'react';
```

with this one

```
const React = require("react")
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation.